# C# Login/Register simple Console application

Tags: c#, console-application

When i create user it stores into the string, but when i try to login with the same(somehow it doesn't exist in the string...)

```
using System;

namespace Exercise4
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Start:
        Console.WriteLine("Za login stisnete 1 ili za register 2");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();



        bool successfull = false;
        while (!successfull)
        {
            var arrUsers = new Users[]
        {
            new Users("tomas","samsung",2605),
            new Users("stefan","pasle",15),
            new Users("dimitar","jovanov",32)
        };  
            if (input == "1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Write your username:");
                var username = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your password:");
                var password = Console.ReadLine();


                foreach (Users user in arrUsers)
                {
                    if (username == user.username && password == user.password)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have successfully logged in !!!");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        successfull = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (username != user.username || password != user.password)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your username or password is incorect, try again !!!");
                        Console.ReadLine();

                        break;

                    }
                }

            }

            else if (input == "2")
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Enter your username:");
                var username = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter your password:");
                var password = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter your id:");
                int id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


                Array.Resize(ref arrUsers, arrUsers.Length + 1);
                arrUsers[arrUsers.Length - 1] = new Users(username,password, id);
                successfull = true;
                goto Start;



            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Try again !!!");
                break;


            }

        }

    }

}

}
```

Cant figure it out how to do it.

Comment: Ask yourself, "After registering, it goes back to the Start label. What happens to `arrUsers` when it enters the loop again?"

Comment: removes them ? :D but how to put the start into the while loop .... or anything similar to that ? :D

    bool successfull = false;
            while (!successfull)
            {
            Start:
                Console.WriteLine("Za login stisnete 1 ili za register 2");
                var input = Console.ReadLine();
                var arrUsers = new Users[]

i did this but still no desired effect -_-
btw it says : For login press 1 for register 2

Comment: i can't figure it out where is my mistake -_- i know that it starts over again but ......
i did debuggin with it but cannot simply understand
it stores them and when it goes to start deletes them ... don't know why

Comment: Try getting rid of the Start label and the `goto` statement. See what happens. Beyond that, use the debugger to examine the state of your program so you can get a better idea of what's happening and what you need to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var arrUsers = new Users[]
        {
            new Users("tomas","samsung",2605),
            new Users("stefan","pasle",15),
            new Users("dimitar","jovanov",32)
        };

        Start:
        Console.WriteLine("Za login stisnete 1 ili za register 2");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();



        bool successfull = false;
        while (!successfull)
        {

            if (input == "1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Write your username:");
                var username = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your password:");
                var password = Console.ReadLine();


                foreach (Users user in arrUsers)
                {
                    if (username == user.username && password == user.password)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have successfully logged in !!!");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        successfull = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!successfull)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your username or password is incorect, try again !!!");
                }

            }

            else if (input == "2")
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Enter your username:");
                var username = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter your password:");
                var password = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter your id:");
                int id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


                Array.Resize(ref arrUsers, arrUsers.Length + 1);
                arrUsers[arrUsers.Length - 1] = new Users(username, password, id);
                successfull = true;
                goto Start;

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Try again !!!");
                break;


            }

        }

    }
}

public class Users
{
    public string username;
    public string password;
    private int id;

    public Users(string username, string password, int id)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I made some changes on your code please check the difference

I placed the arrUsers before Start so that the reference wont change when you goto Start